# How can you force the Linux kernel to use a specific block size for a disk?

Tags: linux, data-recovery, usb-device

I work in IT. Sometimes we're asked to get data off of drives that have failed. We have various SATA-to-USB, ATA-to-USB, etc. adapters for this task. But, sometimes they report the wrong block size to the computer (or maybe they're not reporting any block size at all, and my Linux laptop is just assuming the wrong size). How do I tell the kernel to use a 512-byte block size when it wants to use a 4096-byte block size or vice versa?

I'm running Fedora, kernel version 5.2.11-100.fc29.x86_64, if that makes any difference.

---

Here's some extra data I was asked for (device 16 (sdb) is the Coolmax, and 19 (sdd) is the StarTech):

```
$ sudo lsusb | grep JMicron
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 152d:2338 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JM20337 Hi-Speed USB to SATA & PATA Combo Bridge
Bus 001 Device 019: ID 152d:2338 JMicron Technology Corp. / JMicron USA Technology Corp. JM20337 Hi-Speed USB to SATA & PATA Combo Bridge

$ cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/logical_block_size 
4096
$ cat /sys/block/sdd/queue/logical_block_size 
4096

$ cat /sys/block/sdb/queue/physical_block_size
4096
$ cat /sys/block/sdd/queue/physical_block_size 
4096

$ sudo sg_readcap /dev/sdb
Read Capacity results:
   Last logical block address=366284645 (0x15d50f65), Number of blocks=366284646
   Logical block length=4096 bytes
Hence:
   Device size: 1500301910016 bytes, 1430799.4 MiB, 1500.30 GB
$ sudo sg_readcap /dev/sdd
Read Capacity results:
   Last logical block address=122096645 (0x7470c05), Number of blocks=122096646
   Logical block length=4096 bytes
Hence:
   Device size: 500107862016 bytes, 476940.0 MiB, 500.11 GB

$ sudo sg_readcap -16 /dev/sdb
Read Capacity results:
   Protection: prot_en=0, p_type=0, p_i_exponent=0
   Logical block provisioning: lbpme=0, lbprz=0
   Last logical block address=2930277167 (0xaea87b2f), Number of logical blocks=2930277168
   Logical block length=512 bytes
   Logical blocks per physical block exponent=0
   Lowest aligned logical block address=0
Hence:
   Device size: 1500301910016 bytes, 1430799.4 MiB, 1500.30 GB
$ sudo sg_readcap -16 /dev/sdd
Read Capacity results:
   Protection: prot_en=0, p_type=0, p_i_exponent=0
   Logical block provisioning: lbpme=0, lbprz=0
   Last logical block address=976773167 (0x3a38602f), Number of logical blocks=976773168
   Logical block length=512 bytes
   Logical blocks per physical block exponent=0
   Lowest aligned logical block address=0
Hence:
   Device size: 500107862016 bytes, 476940.0 MiB, 500.11 GB
```

Comment: Funny that you mention Fedora Core. Core is not a thing for 12 years already. :-)

Comment: Reporting a 4096 bytes physical size when it's really 512 bytes is odd. Which hardware combination does give you that error? Usually it's a faulty USB-to-SATA bridge (e.g. JMicron) which coulds off a particular SCSI command and reports 4096 physical size disks as 512 byte disks.

Comment: @TooTea Oops, that's supposed to be Fedora Workstation. Or is it just Fedora? Whatever.

Comment: @dirkt The one I'm using now is Coolmax branded, with no model number or anything on it, but dmesg reports the manufacturer as JMicron. I also have a StarTech UNIDOCK2U, which dmesg **also** reports as manufactured by JMicron. Huh.

Comment: So it looks like the stupid JMicron bug - but the interesting part is still that it reports a size of 4096 instead of 512 (i.e. the other way round compared to mine). Can you confirm that? Because if yes, it doesn't just cut the SCSI command short like I assumed.

Comment: @dirkt Yes, it's reporting a block size of 4096, but this is a slightly older disk that still uses 512-byte blocks. So, if you run fdisk on this 1.4TB disk, it claims that the partition is actually 10.9TB.

Comment: So it's reporting the wrong *logical* block size, not the *physical* block size as for me? That's odd. Can you edit your question with the output of `lsusb | grep JMicron`, `cat /sys/block/sdx/queue/logical_block_size`, `cat /sys/block/sdx/queue/physical_block_size`, `sg_readcap /dev/sdx` and `sg_readcap -16 /dev/sdx`, where `sdx` is the harddisk in question? You need `sg3_utils` for the last two.

Comment: @dirkt It's apparently reporting both the logical and the physical sizes incorrectly. I've added the output of those commands to my answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `losetup` to create a loop device with a different logical sector size.

```
   -b, --sector-size size
          Set  the  logical sector size of the loop device in bytes (since
          Linux 4.14). The option may be used when create a new  loop  de‐
          vice as well as stand-alone command to modify sector size of the
          already existing loop device.
```

So for example:

```
# losetup --find --show --sector-size 512 /dev/thething
/dev/loop2
# losetup --find --show --sector-size 2048 /dev/thething
/dev/loop3
# losetup --find --show --sector-size 4096 /dev/thething
/dev/loop4
# blockdev --getss /dev/loop2
512
# blockdev --getss /dev/loop3
2048
# blockdev --getss /dev/loop4
4096
```

Changing already existing loop device:

```
# blockdev --getss /dev/loop4
4096
# losetup --sector-size 1024 /dev/loop4
# blockdev --getss /dev/loop4
1024
```

However, some USB adapters also have other oddities, like some do not give you access to the full capacity of the drive, like some USB bridges have encryption or RAID capabilities so they might reserve a few sectors for metadata.

So if possible, it's preferrable to use hardware that does what you want, without workarounds.

Comment: "it's preferrable to use hardware that does what you want, without workarounds." Yeah, that'd be nice.